# How to get the result of OnPostExecute() to main activity because AsyncTask is a separate class?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have this two classes. My main Activity and the one that extends the `AsyncTask`, Now in my main Activity I need to get the result from the `OnPostExecute()` in the `AsyncTask`. How can I pass or get the result to my main Activity?

Here is the sample codes.

My main Activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    AasyncTask asyncTask = new AasyncTask();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle aBundle) {
        super.onCreate(aBundle);            

        //Calling the AsyncTask class to start to execute.  
        asyncTask.execute(a.targetServer); 

        //Creating a TextView.
        TextView displayUI = asyncTask.dataDisplay;
        displayUI = new TextView(this);
        this.setContentView(tTextView); 
    }

}
```

This is the AsyncTask class

```
public class AasyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

TextView dataDisplay; //store the data  
String soapAction = "http://sample.com"; //SOAPAction header line. 
String targetServer = "https://sampletargeturl.com"; //Target Server.

//SOAP Request.
String soapRequest = "<sample XML request>";    



@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... string) {

String responseStorage = null; //storage of the response

try {


    //Uses URL and HttpURLConnection for server connection. 
    URL targetURL = new URL(targetServer);
    HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) targetURL.openConnection();
    httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
    httpCon.setDoInput(true);
    httpCon.setUseCaches(false); 
    httpCon.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

    //properties of SOAPAction header
    httpCon.addRequestProperty("SOAPAction", soapAction);
    httpCon.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"); 
    httpCon.addRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + soapRequest.length());
    httpCon.setRequestMethod(HttpPost.METHOD_NAME);


    //sending request to the server.
    OutputStream outputStream = httpCon.getOutputStream(); 
    Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
    writer.write(soapRequest);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();


    //getting the response from the server
    InputStream inputStream = httpCon.getInputStream(); 
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    ByteArrayBuffer byteArrayBuffer = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);

    int intResponse = httpCon.getResponseCode();

    while ((intResponse = bufferedReader.read()) != -1) {
        byteArrayBuffer.append(intResponse);
    }

    responseStorage = new String(byteArrayBuffer.toByteArray()); 

    } catch (Exception aException) {
    responseStorage = aException.getMessage(); 
    }
    return responseStorage;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    aTextView.setText(result);

}       

}
```

Comment: You can create an interface like HelmiB explained or you can create a local broadcast receiver You can see the sample broadcast reciver implementation here http://wiki.workassis.com/android-local-broadcast-receiver/

Comment: Why don't use Observer pattern?

Answer (score 779, accepted):

Easy:

1. Create `interface` class, where `String output` is optional, or can be whatever variables you want to return.

   ```
    public interface AsyncResponse {
        void processFinish(String output);
    }
   ```
2. Go to your `AsyncTask` class, and declare interface `AsyncResponse` as a field :

   ```
    public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
      public AsyncResponse delegate = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
          delegate.processFinish(result);
        }
     }
   ```
3. In your main Activity you need to `implements` interface `AsyncResponse`.

   ```
    public class MainActivity implements AsyncResponse{
      MyAsyncTask asyncTask =new MyAsyncTask();

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         //this to set delegate/listener back to this class
         asyncTask.delegate = this;

         //execute the async task 
         asyncTask.execute();
      }

      //this override the implemented method from asyncTask
      @Override
      void processFinish(String output){
         //Here you will receive the result fired from async class 
         //of onPostExecute(result) method.
       }
     }
   ```

---

UPDATE

I didn't know this is such a favourite to many of you. So here's the simple and convenience way to use `interface`.

still using same `interface`. FYI, you may combine this into `AsyncTask` class.

in `AsyncTask` class :

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

  // you may separate this or combined to caller class.
  public interface AsyncResponse {
        void processFinish(String output);
  }

  public AsyncResponse delegate = null;

    public MyAsyncTask(AsyncResponse delegate){
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      delegate.processFinish(result);
    }
}
```

do this in your `Activity` class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  
   MyAsyncTask asyncTask = new MyAsyncTask(new AsyncResponse(){
    
     @Override
     void processFinish(String output){
     //Here you will receive the result fired from async class 
     //of onPostExecute(result) method.
     }
  }).execute();

 }
```

Or, implementing the interface on the Activity again

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
    implements AsyncResponse{
      
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //execute the async task 
        new MyAsyncTask(this).execute();
    }
      
    //this override the implemented method from AsyncResponse
    @Override
    void processFinish(String output){
        //Here you will receive the result fired from async class 
        //of onPostExecute(result) method.
    }
}
```

As you can see 2 solutions above, the first and third one, it needs to create method `processFinish`, the other one, the method is inside the caller parameter. The third  is more neat because there is no nested anonymous class.

**Tip**: Change `String output`, `String response`, and `String result` to different matching types in order to get different objects.

Comment: Totally wrote all of that up and then saw your answer :) Here's to thinking alike! +1.  Also this way multiple things can listen to the results of the AsyncTask!

Comment: Yes that's true, that's the function of `interface`. i forgot to set delegate though :). have added in `onCreate`.

Comment: this definitely work. try to post some of work you have done so far, especially the `AsyncTask` class

Comment: Hi. thank you for your reply, I edited my question and included the sample code. It's the original code I have. How can I put the interface with that? and I think I'm not getting the variables in a right way from the Aasynctask.

Comment: it's your `AsyncTask ` class. in this case your `AasyncTask`. i edited my answer based on your class you posted.

Comment: I am getting nullpointer exception because delegate is set to null, please clearify it

Comment: Just a note for .net developers, one can use AutoResetEvents to achieve this and there is also a java implementation for autoresetevents but this is much cleaner. By the way, is ProcessFinish thread safe?

Comment: i would like to call doinbackground method in main activity, how can i achieve that?

Comment: With this solution, I get an empty blank page before my next activity opens direclyt after.

Comment: I'm also getting a NullPointerException on the line:         delegate.processFinish(s);

by the way, I'm using a fragment that is implementing the AsyncResponse

Comment: I want to use the same Interface for a number of AsyncTask. Hence I modified the Interface as follows :                             public interface IntrfcResponseManager {
 void processResponse(String source,boolean output);
}                                                                            For this I cannot use asyncTask.delegate = this; in my MainActivity. How to do in this case ?

Comment: for all those who are getting null pointer pass your interface to your asyncTask class constructor then assign it to a variable and then call processfinish() on that variable. For reference see accepted asnwer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963691/android-asynctask-sending-callbacks-to-ui

Comment: @Sunny you are right...

also, we have to initialize the async object for async.delegate = this; to work..

Comment: Can the void processFinish() or whatever method you create be implemented in any Activity? or does it have to be the Activity that implements the ASYNCTASK?

Comment: Here is a extended example of [protocols](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26820666/2835520)

Comment: This worked so well and helped me restructure a bit of code that was getting a little out of control. Thanks!

Comment: public void onPostExecute(HandleJSON data) {

      delegate.processFinish(data);   at this step error occured.

Comment: I can't decide if this method is better, or the `new MyTask().execute().get()` one. Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why is it an accepted answer, if it is not workable and incomplete? Still not clear of how to solve nullpointer exception. Even if we create a constructor (as Sunny proposed) in asyncTask class, then how do we call this constructor?

Comment: Thank you so much. this is the only solution which i find robust, i tried everything...even google documentation says to use get method to get return values but it ends the async and UI starts hanging...this is the best solution..Clean and Clever.. Made my day :)

Comment: @KaranDatwani Would like to know, which option you prefer ? the first or second solution?

Comment: @HelmiB Boss i am using your line of code but i am facing some problem with your code because i want to use string variable result in on create method which is in processFinish method in main activity java file and in on create method it give null object reference when i use to "c = new JSONArray(resultofasync);"

Comment: @HelmiB I'm also getting a null pointer. I implemented the updated version of your solution. Any thoughts?

Comment: just a side note create a weak reference of listener (Activity) in the AsyncTask class and check if not null on post execute to avoid memory leaks

Comment: Is there a generic name for this pattern? Are there other ways to achieve this? From an Object Oriented thinking, how can I think about this solution from scratch?

Comment: What Is the disadvantage with using a class level variable at the activity and accessing it inside the Asynctask?

Comment: I thought the same thing! i was actually writing this solution, then i came to see if it is a better solution but i guess i was in the right path

Comment: I am getting the error "Inner classes cannot have static declarations"

Comment: Could it be possible to update data in AsyncTask to its `LiveData<...>` member and adding an observer to observe data changes?

Comment: I get this error when I follow your steps (the second one): "attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public". could you clarify whats wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 25):

There are a few options:

- Nest the `AsyncTask` class within your `Activity` class. Assuming you don't use the same task in multiple activities, this is the easiest way. All your code stays the same, you just move the existing task class to be a nested class inside your activity's class.

  ```
  public class MyActivity extends Activity {
      // existing Activity code
      ...

      private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
          // existing AsyncTask code
          ...
      }
  }
  ```
- Create a custom constructor for your `AsyncTask` that takes a reference to your `Activity`. You would instantiate the task with something like `new MyAsyncTask(this).execute(param1, param2)`.

  ```
  public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
      private Activity activity;

      public MyAsyncTask(Activity activity) {
          this.activity = activity;
      }

      // existing AsyncTask code
      ...
  }
  ```

Comment: In the second option: Why go through the pain of a constructor and a field if the class is not `static`? Just use any `fieldOrMethod` from `MyActivity` or `MyActivity.this.fieldOrMethod` if it's shadowed.

Comment: @TWiStErRob The second assumes `MyAsyncTask` is *not* an inner class.

Comment: Oh, sorry, `private`/`protected` for top level classes is not allowed, hence I thought it must be a non-`static` inner class.

Comment: Just be careful that inner class AsyncTask can be a source of memory leaks as explained here http://garena.github.io/blog/2014/09/10/android-memory-leaks/

Comment: Holding onto an Activity reference is also a memory leak. The callback approach is far better than this

Answer (score 19):

I felt the below approach is very easy.

I have declared an interface for callback

```
public interface AsyncResponse {
    void processFinish(Object output);
}
```

Then created asynchronous Task for responding all type of parallel requests

```
 public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {

    public AsyncResponse delegate = null;//Call back interface

    public MyAsyncTask(AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
        delegate = asyncResponse;//Assigning call back interfacethrough constructor
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {

      //My Background tasks are written here

      return {resutl Object}

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        delegate.processFinish(result);
    }

}
```

Then Called the asynchronous task when clicking a button in activity Class.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Button mbtnPress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPress);

    mbtnPress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                MyAsyncTask asyncTask =new MyAsyncTask(new AsyncResponse() {

                    @Override
                    public void processFinish(Object output) {
                        Log.d("Response From Asynchronous task:", (String) output);

                        mbtnPress.setText((String) output);
                   }
                });

                asyncTask.execute(new Object[] { "Your request to aynchronous task class is giving here.." });


            }
        });

    }



}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 19):

You can try this code in your Main class. 
That worked for me, but i have implemented  methods in other way

```
try {
    String receivedData = new AsyncTask().execute("http://yourdomain.com/yourscript.php").get();
} 
catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException ei) {
    ei.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why this would help OP with their issue?

Comment: That helped me. I tryed in other way like the answer from @HelmiB but i get no results

Comment: Ok sorry for my answer. She need to call the AsyncTask class, and then to put a parameter to this call. AsyncTask is defined by 3 generic types: 1 params(server domain or other param) 2 progress(can be void), 3 result.     All of these types can be: JSONObject, or strings, or any data types.   When you have  a AsyncTask class you should define where to send the data.    ex:   asyncTask.execute("https://sampletargeturl.com").get();

Comment: When using this method, I got a warning on Logcat: "I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." How to deal with this? Does UI get freeze when waiting for returned from AsyncTask?

Comment: @NicuP you might forgot to call `execute()`, see my answer, I've added comment there. you might want to check my updated answer. hope this helps.

Answer (score 17):

This answer might be late but I would like to mention few things when your `Activity` dependent on `AsyncTask`. That would help you in prevent crashes and memory management. As already mentioned in above answers go with `interface`, we also say them callbacks. They will work as an informer, but never ever send **strong** reference of `Activity` or `interface` always use **weak** reference in those cases.

Please refer to below screenshot to findout how that can cause issues.

[image]

As you can see if we started `AsyncTask` with a **strong** reference then there is no guarantee that our `Activity`/`Fragment` will be alive till we get data, so it would be better to use `WeakReference` in those cases and that will also help in memory management as we will never hold the strong reference of our `Activity` then it will be eligible for garbage collection after its distortion.

Check below code snippet to find out how to use awesome WeakReference -

`MyTaskInformer.java` Interface which will work as an informer.

```
public interface MyTaskInformer {

    void onTaskDone(String output);

}
```

`MySmallAsyncTask.java` AsyncTask to do long running task, which will use `WeakReference`.

```
public class MySmallAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    // ***** Hold weak reference *****
    private WeakReference<MyTaskInformer> mCallBack;

    public MySmallAsyncTask(MyTaskInformer callback) {
        this.mCallBack = new WeakReference<>(callback);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        // Here do whatever your task is like reading/writing file
        // or read data from your server or any other heavy task

        // Let us suppose here you get response, just return it
        final String output = "Any out, mine is just demo output";

        // Return it from here to post execute
        return output;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        // Here you can't guarantee that Activity/Fragment is alive who started this AsyncTask

        // Make sure your caller is active

        final MyTaskInformer callBack = mCallBack.get();

        if(callBack != null) {
            callBack.onTaskDone(s);
        }
    }
}
```

`MainActivity.java` This class is used to start my `AsyncTask` implement `interface` on this class and `override` this mandatory method.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MyTaskInformer {

    private TextView mMyTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mMyTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_text_view);

        // Start your AsyncTask and pass reference of MyTaskInformer in constructor
        new MySmallAsyncTask(this).execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskDone(String output) {

        // Here you will receive output only if your Activity is alive.
        // no need to add checks like if(!isFinishing())

        mMyTextView.setText(output);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do it in a few lines, just override onPostExecute when you call your AsyncTask. Here is an example for you:

```
new AasyncTask()
{
    @Override public void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
       // do whatever you want with result 
    }
}.execute(a.targetServer);
```

I hope it helped you, happy codding :)

Comment: It doesn't work for me. It just doesn't enter to `onPostExecute` method.

Answer (score 6):

in your Oncreate():

`

```
myTask.execute("url");
String result = "";
try {
      result = myTask.get().toString();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
}catch (ExecutionException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
```

}`

Answer (score 4):

You can call the [`get()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29) method of `AsyncTask` (or the overloaded [`get(long, TimeUnit)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29)).  This method will block until the `AsyncTask` has completed its work, at which point it will return you the `Result`.

It would be wise to be doing other work between the creation/start of your async task and calling the `get` method, otherwise you aren't utilizing the async task very efficiently.

Comment: Downvoted vecause get() will block main thread. No reason to use AsyncTask if it will block

Answer (score 4):

Why do people make it so hard.

This should be sufficient.

Do not implement the onPostExecute on the async task, rather implement it on the Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //execute the async task 
    MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask(){
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                //Do your thing
            }       

    }

    task.execute("Param");

}


}
```

Comment: This works for me. It is the simple and the easiest to understand. I think it is making use of what Java is designed to do. Thanks.  PS: Is it necessary to add an `@Override`?

Comment: No. @Override is just an annotation. So you are telling java compiler that you are intending to override the method and get informed if you are not doing so.

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own listener. It's same as [HelmiB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12575319/3525814)'s answer but looks more natural:

Create listener interface:

```
public interface myAsyncTaskCompletedListener {
    void onMyAsynTaskCompleted(int responseCode, String result);
}
```

Then write your asynchronous task:

```
public class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private myAsyncTaskCompletedListener listener;
    private int responseCode = 0;

    public myAsyncTask() {
    }

    public myAsyncTask(myAsyncTaskCompletedListener listener, int responseCode) {
        this.listener = listener;
        this.responseCode = responseCode;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String result;
        String param = (params.length == 0) ? null : params[0];
        if (param != null) {
            // Do some background jobs, like httprequest...
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String finalResult) {
        super.onPostExecute(finalResult);
        if (!isCancelled()) {
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onMyAsynTaskCompleted(responseCode, finalResult);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally implement listener in activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements myAsyncTaskCompletedListener {

    @Override
    public void onMyAsynTaskCompleted(int responseCode, String result) {

        switch (responseCode) {
            case TASK_CODE_ONE: 
                // Do something for CODE_ONE
                break;
            case TASK_CODE_TWO:
                // Do something for CODE_TWO
                break;
            default: 
                // Show some error code
        }        
    }
```

And this is how you can call asyncTask:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Some other codes...
        new myAsyncTask(this,TASK_CODE_ONE).execute("Data for background job");
        // And some another codes...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can make something like this:

1. Create class which implements AsyncTask

   ```
   // TASK 
   public class SomeClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>>
   {

       private OnTaskExecutionFinished _task_finished_event;

       public interface OnTaskExecutionFinished
       {
           public void OnTaskFihishedEvent(String Reslut);
       }

       public void setOnTaskFinishedEvent(OnTaskExecutionFinished _event)
       {
           if(_event != null)
           {
               this._task_finished_event = _event;
           }
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute()
       {
           super.onPreExecute();

       }

       @Override
       protected String doInBackground(Void... params)
       {
           // do your background task here ...

           return "Done!";
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String result)
       {
           super.onPostExecute(result);
           if(this._task_finished_event != null)
           {
               this._task_finished_event.OnTaskFihishedEvent(result);
           }
           else
           {
               Log.d("SomeClass", "task_finished even is null");
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add in Main Activity

   ```
   // MAIN ACTIVITY
   public class MyActivity extends ListActivity
   {
      ...
       SomeClass _some_class = new SomeClass();
       _someclass.setOnTaskFinishedEvent(new _some_class.OnTaskExecutionFinished()
       {
       @Override
       public void OnTaskFihishedEvent(String result)
       {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                   "Phony thread finished: " + result,
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }

      });
      _some_class.execute();
      ...
    }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Create a static member in your Activity class. Then assign the value during the `onPostExecute`

For example, if the result of your AsyncTask is a String, create a public static string in your Activity

`public static String dataFromAsyncTask;`

Then, in the `onPostExecute` of the AsyncTask, simply make a static call to your main class and set the value.

`MainActivity.dataFromAsyncTask = "result blah";`

Comment: what are the possibilities of memory leak in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I make it work by using threading and handler/message.
Steps as follow:
Declare a progress Dialog

```
ProgressDialog loadingdialog;
```

Create a function to close dialog when operation is finished.

```
   private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        loadingdialog.dismiss();

    }
    };
```

Code your Execution details:

```
 public void startUpload(String filepath) {
    loadingdialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Uploading", "Uploading Please Wait", true);
    final String _path = filepath;
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                UploadFile(_path, getHostName(), getPortNo());
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("threadmessage", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **"protocols"** to delegate or provide data to the `AsynTask`.

**Delegates and Data Sources**

A delegate is an object that acts on behalf of, or in coordination with, another object when that object encounters an event in a program. ([Apple definition](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html))

**protocols are interfaces that define some methods to delegate some behaviors.**

[Here is a complete example!!!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26820666/2835520)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public class SomAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, JSONObject> {

    private CallBack callBack;

    public interface CallBack {
        void async( JSONObject jsonResult );
        void sync( JSONObject jsonResult );
        void progress( Integer... status );
        void cancel();
    }

    public SomAsyncTask(CallBack callBack) {
        this.callBack = callBack;
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... strings) {

        JSONObject dataJson = null;

        //TODO query, get some dataJson

        if(this.callBack != null)
            this.callBack.async( dataJson );// asynchronize with MAIN LOOP THREAD

        return dataJson;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        if(this.callBack != null)
            this.callBack.progress(values);// synchronize with MAIN LOOP THREAD

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        super.onPostExecute(jsonObject);

        if(this.callBack != null)
            this.callBack.sync(jsonObject);// synchronize with MAIN LOOP THREAD
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();

        if(this.callBack != null)
            this.callBack.cancel();

    }
}
```

And usage example:

```
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         final Context _localContext = getContext();
         SomeAsyncTask.CallBack someCallBack = new SomeAsyncTask.CallBack() {

                @Override
                public void async(JSONObject jsonResult) {//async thread
                    //some async process, e.g. send data to server...
                }

                @Override
                public void sync(JSONObject jsonResult) {//sync thread
                    //get result...

                    //get some resource of Activity variable...
                    Resources resources = _localContext.getResources();
                }

                @Override
                public void progress(Integer... status) {//sync thread
                    //e.g. change status progress bar...
                }

                @Override
                public void cancel() {

                }

            };

            new SomeAsyncTask( someCallBack )
                                .execute("someParams0", "someParams1", "someParams2");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably going overboard a bit but i provided call backs for both the execution code and the results. obviously for thread safety you want to be careful what you access in your execution callback.

The AsyncTask implementation:

```
public class AsyncDbCall<ExecuteType,ResultType> extends AsyncTask<ExecuteType, Void,  
ResultType>
{
    public interface ExecuteCallback<E, R>
    {
        public R execute(E executeInput);
    }
    public interface PostExecuteCallback<R>
    {
        public void finish(R result);
    }

    private PostExecuteCallback<ResultType> _resultCallback = null;
    private ExecuteCallback<ExecuteType,ResultType> _executeCallback = null;


    AsyncDbCall(ExecuteCallback<ExecuteType,ResultType> executeCallback, PostExecuteCallback<ResultType> postExecuteCallback)
    {
        _resultCallback = postExecuteCallback;
        _executeCallback = executeCallback;
    }

    AsyncDbCall(ExecuteCallback<ExecuteType,ResultType> executeCallback)
    {
        _executeCallback = executeCallback;
    }

    @Override
    protected ResultType doInBackground(final ExecuteType... params)
    {
        return  _executeCallback.execute(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ResultType result)
    {
        if(_resultCallback != null)
            _resultCallback.finish(result);
    }
}
```

A callback:

```
 AsyncDbCall.ExecuteCallback<Device, Device> updateDeviceCallback = new 
 AsyncDbCall.ExecuteCallback<Device, Device>()
    {
        @Override
        public Device execute(Device device)
        {
            deviceDao.updateDevice(device);
            return device;
        }
    };
```

And finally execution of the async task:

```
 new AsyncDbCall<>(addDeviceCallback, resultCallback).execute(device);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you been through [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) , if not please read.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Depending on the nature of result data, you should choose best possible option you can think of.

It is a great choice to use an **Interface**

some other options would be..

- If the AsyncTask class is defined inside the very class you want to
  use the result in.Use a **static global variable or get()**  , use it from
  outer class (*volatile variable* if necessary). but should be aware of the AsyncTask *progress* or should at least make sure that it have finished the task and result is
  available through global variable / get() method. you may use
  *polling, [onProgressUpdate(Progress...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate(Progress...)), synchronization or interfaces (Which ever suits best for you)*
- If the Result is compatible to be a sharedPreference entry or it is okay to be saved as a file in the memory you could **save it** even from 
  the background task itself and could use the *onPostExecute()* method
  to get notified when the result is available in the memory.
- If the string is small enough, and is to be used with start of an
  activity. it is possible to use **intents** (*putExtra()*) within
  *onPostExecute()* , but remember that *static contexts aren't that safe*
  to deal with.
- If possible, you can call a **static method** from the
  onPostExecute() method, with the result being your *parameter*