# android - Several http-requests at same time

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httprequest, httpclient, background-process

i am trying to make several http-requests at same time and on same Activity using `httpclient` and `Asynctask`

while i use `.execute().get();` everything goes all right. but i feel request is not background and some times project hangs and error :
**project too busy [wait] [force close]**

**my asynctask class:**

```
private class get_sessions extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        HttpGet post = new HttpGet(ServerName+"/?GetSessionsForAndroid");
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                break;
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result1){
        try{
            JSONObject result = new JSONObject(result1);
            aktuell_date_u = result.optString("aktuell_date_u").toString();
            set_check = result.optString("set_check").toString();
            pd.cancel();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

what must i do else, please show me an example

thanks

Comment: Put your async task code here.

Comment: Instead of .execute().get(); only use .execute();

Comment: @DhavalPatel project closes because multi `asynctask` or `httppost` at same time

Comment: .get() method "Waits for AysncTask to complete, and then retrieves its result.". So I think this is causing UI freezing issue.

Comment: @DhavalPatel i want to send multi request at same time and background on asynctask, these are all important, my problem is that, can not create multi asynctask at same time on same activity

Comment: Why don't you use "IntentService".

Comment: It's not good to use get() method which will block caller thread. Try to use callback method using interface.

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar my problem is not callback

Comment: @Nabi The Execute.get method waits if needed for the result to be available. It will blocks the caller thread to wait untill the previous asynctask get result returned.Check once with this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10972226/4596556

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar i know what does `.get()` so i want another solution to send multi request

Comment: @Nabi As per my understanding if you implement callback then no worry about waiting for get() result.The process become async. :)

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar please show an example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93457/discussion-between-nabi-and-madhukar-hebbar).