# Android ASyncTask Return type mismatch

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm pulling my hair out with what looks to be a really simple thing to do. Surely this is just a typo or something stupid, but I'm just not seeing it...

I have an ASyncTask class defined as such (and it compiles fine)

```
    public class SectionRetrieval extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Section>>
    {


        @Override
        protected List<Section> doInBackground(Void... voids)
        {        
            List<Section> sections = new ArrayList<Section>();

            ...

            return sections;
        }
     }
```

In my app I attempt to call it as such

```
    List<Section> sections = new SectionRetrieval().execute();
```

But this doesn't compile

```
Error:(472, 63) Gradle: error: incompatible types: 

AsyncTask<Void,Void,List<Section>> cannot be converted to List<Section>
```

I've tried separating the creation of the new SectionalRetrieval instance and the call the .execute(). No such luck. It really does seem to think execute() is really trying to return an instance of SectionalRetrieval.

So how did I make it think that's what I wanted?

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10972142/3629732 but this one not recommended to performance issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive whatever you return from doInBackground in the parameter of onPostExecute.

You update the UI from onPostExecute as well.

You could do `execute().get()` to have it compile, probably, but I wouldn't recommend that

Comment: Well, I;m not trying to update the UI with this. It's strictly a network call I'm doing asyncronously.

Comment: Then remove the assignment if you don't need it. Just call execute

Comment: You seem to be returning an Arraylist of some sections, so certainly, you want those to be displayed *eventually*, otherwise, what's the point in returning anything?

Comment: Well the point of the Async task is to make the network call and get the List. I'll need it downstream. I'm okay with even making this call at startup time. It doesn't need to interact with the UI, but I do need the data. 

I suppose the point is that I shouldn't call this from the activity or I;m making my user wait for the results?

Comment: Right. And downstream is onPostExecute, which is where you need to do the assignment. One of my favorite posts is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a

Comment: It seems awfully fraught with peril to do what I want this way. Whose to say the calling Activity even exists anymore by the time the data is retrieved.

I think what I want is to do this at startup before any activity runs, assuming I can. The only reason I'm doing this through ASyncTask is because Network calls have to be made that way.

Comment: The sections need to be stored somewhere certainly. (It's for a Dialog Box List). The idea of populating an AlertDialog with data one gets from an ASyncTask would seem to be something Shrodinger would appreciate.

The answer is move the AlertBuilder code to PostExecute. Got it :)

Comment: Not all network requests have to be in AsyncTasks, they just have to be off the UI thread.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902716/comparison-of-android-networking-libraries-okhttp-retrofit-volley

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do to run this is:

```
new SectionRetrieval().execute();
```

This method doesn't return anything. It's is an asynchronous task, thus no return value. Once the task is done, `onPostExecute` will run, and that is where you handle the return values, not where you call the execute method.